# name 'coco' is not defined

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have tried to clone coco API to download a specific class from coco dataset, but when I run codes in Google Colaboratory, it gives me this error: `name 'coco' is not defined`.

```py
!git clone https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi
#display COCO categories
cats = coco.loadCats(coco.getCatIds())
nms=[cat['name'] for cat in cats]
print('COCO categories: \n{}\n'.format(' '.join(nms)))

# get all images containing given categories (I'm selecting the "bird")
catIds = coco.getCatIds(catNms=['bird']);
imgIds = coco.getImgIds(catIds=catIds);
```

Comment: Did you forget to `import coco`?

Comment: Did you install the package and import it according to [the instructions](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is from the example in https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi/blob/master/PythonAPI/demos/pycocoDemo.ipynb

And you need to copy some more lines:

```
from pycocotools.coco import COCO
# ... skipped some lines here
# initialize COCO api for instance annotations
coco=COCO(annFile)
cats = coco.loadCats(coco.getCatIds())
nms=[cat['name'] for cat in cats]
print('COCO categories: \n{}\n'.format(' '.join(nms)))

# get all images containing given categories (I'm selecting the "bird")
catIds = coco.getCatIds(catNms=['bird']);
imgIds = coco.getImgIds(catIds=catIds);
```

Comment: And the part from up higher than defines `annFile`...